# #Ref error when delete one of the sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have sheets from 1 to 50 and a summary sheet that has formulas based on sheet 1 to sheet 50 (very long formula!). However, whenever I run the macro, the macro will delete one of the 50 sheets and all my formulas in summary sheet becomes #Ref.

I know I can use Indirect function however I have really long formula and the formula in one cell actually refer to all 50 sheets. That will take a lot of time to put indirect function 1 by 1 to refer to all 50 sheets.

For example: the formula in one of the cell is:

```
if(sheet1!A1=2,1,0)+if(sheet2!A1 = 2,1,0)+...+if(sheet50!A1=2,1,0)
```

and I have to drag this formula along the column and across row.

Is there a way to do this quick and get rid of the #Ref error? I don't mind doing this in macro or formula based. PLease help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to get rid of the `#Ref!` and still use your macro? You can copy all cells in the summary sheet and paste as values (Paste special > Paste values) to remove the formulas.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/formulatips/qt/REF_error.htm)

Comment: You could add logic to the macro to modify the formulas in the summary sheet before the sheet delete and then put the modified formulas back in the summary sheet; you could try to search and replace the #REF values in the search - I wasn't able to get this to work by hand, but [**see this thread**](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=147555) for some ideas on how to do this programmatically (I'll try to figure it out for my own satisfaction, as well).

Comment: after 50th sheet deletion is there new sheet which will replace one missing or you need to stay with 49 sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Add something like the following to your macro after the delete sheet operation. With the proper references, it will replace all instances of the #REF formula in the summary sheet. You may have to be creative to tailor the `WHAT:=` clause so that it matches the #REF clauses of the formulas.

```
   Range("<summary sheet name>").Replace What:="+IF(#REF!*)", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
       ReplaceFormat:=False
```

PS: Be sure to test this out on a copy of your sheet first!

Answer (score 0):

You can add some code before delete, that will delete expression with sheet name, that you want delete.

For example formula like "=Sheet1!B1+Sheet2!B1"    will be    "=+Sheet1!B1"

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim deleteSheetName As String  ' sheet name that you want to delete
    Dim currentFormula As String 
    Dim currentFormulaArr() As String

    deleteSheetName = "Sheet2"
    currentFormula = Mid(Cells(1, 1).formula, 2, Len(Cells(1, 1).formula) - 1)
    currentFormulaArr = Split(currentFormula, "+")
    Cells(1, 1).formula = "="
    For i = 0 To UBound(currentFormulaArr)
        If Not currentFormulaArr(i) Like "*" & deleteSheetName & "*" Then
            Cells(1, 1).formula = Cells(1, 1).formula & "+" & currentFormulaArr(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I make it just for one cell. You need some loops through all used cells in every sheet.
I hope, you understand my idea.

I think, chuff's solution is better and faster, but you can apply his solution before removing the sheet.

```
... Range("<summary sheet name>").Replace What:="+IF(" & deleteSheetName & "*)", ....
```

Sorry for my laughable english.